# Sorting a UI component column from a integer that doesnt exists in magento table

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Im getting my data from a external source, so its not something that can be joined with a data provider, but I need to sort by that field.

My column looks like this (`random_int()` is ofcourse just psudo code, but it will get a integer from an external source)

```php
<?php
namespace My\App\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class FieldData extends Column
{

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = random_int();
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```

But when I try to sort by that field, I will ofcourse get a "main_table.field_data" column does not exists error.

So how do I change how that field should be sortable?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
<?php
namespace My\App\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class FieldData extends Column
{

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $randomInt = random_int();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = (int)$randomInt;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm,

Magento uses the column name for sorting from the database by DataSource, if you want to add your column to sortable you have to convert your source to a table and join the table to the dataProvider collection.

If you can not move that data to a database table you have to customize the addOrder by adding a custom DataProvider that extends vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/DataProvider.php:221.